# Can I add multiple POST methods with rest api?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, post

```java
@PostMapping
public void insertPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    personService.addPerson(person);
}

@PostMapping
public void insertPeople(@RequestBody List<Person> people) {
    personService.addPeople(people);
}
```

I want to be able to have multiple POST methods that would be called depending on what JSON format is passed in (I am using postman for this). For example, in the above code, if I pass in just one Person object, I want to call the first method but if I pass in a List of Person objects I want to call the second method.

Is there an easy way solve this or will I need to come up with some kind of work around method that checks the JSON format and then calls personService.addPerson or personService.addPeople based on the format?

Running both at the same time causes an error understandably, and I have checked each method individually, to make sure that they work by themselves.

I am kind of new to SpringBoot/RestAPI so if anyone has any tips/suggestions on resources I could use to learn better, that would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You must specify different paths for same HTTP method. E.g. `@PostMapping("/people")`

Comment: Even if such a workaround would exist it would not be recommended. Better to redesign your client calls to call different endpoints.

Comment: For the specific example, using a its specific property spring framework can accept the `Person` object as a array and convert it to a list of one element erasing the need of the `insertPerson` method.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. The methods have to have different paths such as

```
@PostMapping("/people")
    public void insertPeople(@RequestBody List<Person> people) {
        personService.addPeople(people);
    }

@PostMapping("/person")
    public void insertPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense everyone, thanks! I'll make the methods have different paths